# How to populate picklist with account records

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-controller

**Controller**

```
public List<SelectOption> getAccountList(){
    List<SelectOption> options = new  List<SelectOption>();
    options = [select name from account limit 10];
    return options;       
}
```

I tried this on my own and i am new to salesforce. This generates a compile time error saying

```
Illegal assignment from List<Account> to List<System.SelectOption>
```

**Visulforce page**

```
<apex:page Controller="WrapperClassNew2" >
<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:selectList size="1" >
                <apex:selectOption value="{!accountList}" >

                </apex:selectOption>
            </apex:selectList>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:form>    
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the right type of object by using a [SelectOption](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_selectoption.htm) constructor:

```
public List<SelectOption> getAccountList(){
    List<SelectOption> options = new  List<SelectOption>();
    for (account a : [select name from account order by name desc limit 10]) {
        options.add(new SelectOption(a.name, a.name));
    }
    return options;       
}
```

Suggest you add an `order by` term to the query as otherwise the order is indeterminate.

Note that many orgs have very large numbers of accounts so using a lookup field that allows a search to be done is often more appropriate than having an impossibly large select list.

**PS**

Instead of:

```
<apex:selectOption value="{!accountList}" >
```

you should use this [apex:selectOptions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectOptions.htm) that expects a list of select options:

```
<apex:selectOptions value="{!accountList}" >
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am getting a runtime error Invalid selectOptions found. Use SelectOption type in Apex.

Comment: @MohitJoshi The change I added as a PS may fix that.

Comment: The value for the selectoption should really be the account Id.